# About connected cobordism and surgery

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, cobordism, surgery-theory

I need to find various ways of performing two surgeries on a collection of circles so that the resulting 2-dimensional cobordism (the trace of the surgeries) is connected.

> How can I find  these ? up to level-preserving diffeomorphism(with pictures).